# Is there any way to change the quality of the video?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am looking at the android youtube API docs and the sample applications. I cannot find any API that describes loading a video and setting its quality (to low or high).

Is there a way to change the quality of a video?

[Android-youtube-api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary)

Comment: We encounter this problem, too. and it is interesting that Android Youtube APP can change quality, but not provide kind of apis for developer...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing ;-)

Unfortunately, there is no method in the Android YT API to do that...

There is a function in the Youtube IFrame API
See: [Playback Quality in IFrame Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality)

So the workaround is to use an IFrame associated with an Android WebView and then, control the video quality.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding Youtube implemented a policy to control quality based on your bandwidth and possibly screen size. In the now deprecated older web based API it was possibly to list quality encodings and stream the desired version directly. But this is no longer an option.